# Azure Function - Guarding against Multiple invocation

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have an Azure function on timer trigger. I have seen multiple instance of it running at the same time. Is there a way I can guard against multiple invocations? I don't want it to run until the previous invocation has completed even if I press the play button on Azure portal for function.For instance the below seems to be started twice when I pressed the run button on portal, think there was already an instance running.

```
2019-02-19T04:25:16  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2019-02-19T04:25:23.353 [Info] Function started (Id=aacaf548-79f1-49ec-8614-e638302b8368)
2019-02-19T04:25:26.639 [Info] Function started (Id=f4abe10c-f2bf-447b-bef7-efe3499420c6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you might be able to achieve this is making function your code synchronous (blocking) and limiting the scale to one instance only. That way, each execution will be a blocking call.

To limit the scale, you could modify the App Setting [WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#websitemaxdynamicapplicationscaleout).

Although the request IDs are different in the [Info] logs, it may not necessarily mean that the requests went to two different instances. I believe, if your code is asynchronous, the same app instance can process multiple requests in parallel.

Comment: If we have to make an Azure Function synchronous and limit the scaling to 1, something tells me that the Azure Function is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Why not? If the OP doesn't care about scale but wants to use the FaaS programming model + automated timer triggers + low costs, it's easy enough to constrain scale? @Shinju, why do you want to only invoke one function at a time though? Just to clarify, the timer trigger you set up is independent of you pressing the "run" button (i.e. if you press "run" when the timer trigger is set to fire, it is expected that your function will be invoked twice). The "run" button is always a one-off.

Comment: @MarieHoeger I have a function which truncates a SQL table and loads the data from an API call. I have two instances running each over and sometimes corrupting the data with duplicates or incomplete load

Comment: @Ankit I don't want it to run at the same time in single instance also. Additionally, I am on consumption plan.

Comment: Got it. If you're using C#, you can add the `[Singleton]` attribute (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912). This will make it the function not run at the same time in a single instance. The App Setting Ankit provided will limit your functions to a single instance.

Comment: Is it possible that your time trigger is very short and first instance of function is still running even after time to trigger another instance. eg. time trigger is 3 min but function takes more than 3 minutes to complete.

Comment: @ShijuSamuel I know this thread is rather old, but I am running into the same issue where I have a function app that has a QueueTrigger.  I am doing something similar to you and using a function to ingest data from storage.  I need for the function to finish ingesting data for one file before it start another as I truncate a staging table, load and then process it.    Did you ever figure out how to control this?  The function is dequeue while it is still processing which allows for another message to come in.  I already have batchSize = 1, maxDequeueCount: 1, newBatchThreshold: 0 set.  Thanks!

Comment: WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT. Nearly 4 years later and this setting is still in preview...